# how to update existing app when new version is available

Tags: android, updates

Update button is showing in play store on the second time when we go to play store from the app, here is what I am tried.

```
//getting the version from j soup library

try {
        newVersion = Jsoup.connect(AppConstant.APP_PLAYSTORE_URL+ "&hl=en")
                .timeout(30000)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .get()
                .select("div.hAyfc:nth-child(4) > span:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)")
                .first()
                .ownText();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



 //compare version name
 if (mLatestVersionName != null && !mLatestVersionName.equals("") &&(Double.parseDouble(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME) !=Double.parseDouble(mLatestVersionName))) {
            openCheckerDialog();
        } 




  //getting callback status from play store either it is updated or not
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == RC_UPDATE_APP_FROM_PLAYSTORE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
     //doing task
        Log.v("Update", "Not Updated");
    }
    else
        openCheckerDialog();
}




 //moving to play store from the app 
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        i.setData(Uri.parse(APP_PLAYSTORE_URL));
                        startActivityForResult(i, RC_UPDATE_APP_FROM_PLAYSTORE);
```

But this is not working as expected, could anyone please help with this? Any suggestion and code review is welcome

Answer (score 0):

**Officially available - A new way to force app update**

- This functionality officially known as "In-app updates"
- In-app updates works only with devices running Android 5.0 (API level
  21) or higher
- requires you to use Play Core library 1.5.0 or higher.

> 2 types of options available for forcing in-app update:

- Flexible - will allow the user to discard the update and continue
  using the application
- Immediate - will show a blocking UI that will
  prompt the user to update.

**Note:** In-App Updates API looks at the **Production, Alpha and Beta** tracks in Google Play. You can’t rely on this API to update old Production versions to Internal Test updates

**Links:**

**Documentation -** https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates

**Play-core library -** https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore#include_playcore

**Reference article with an use case/scenarios covered -** https://medium.com/@malmstein/theres-a-new-update-available-75a2c5bda76e​​​​​​​

> **Note:** When you publish your app an Android App Bundle, the maximum allowed compressed download size of an app using in-app updates is
>   150MB. In-app updates are not compatible with apps that use APK
>   expansion files (.obbfiles).

(4 liked)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
    String newVersion = null;

                try {
                    Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName()  + "&hl=en")
                            .timeout(30000)
                            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                            .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                            .get();
                    if (document != null) {
                        Elements element = document.getElementsContainingOwnText("Current Version");
                        for (Element ele : element) {
                            if (ele.siblingElements() != null) {
                                Elements sibElemets = ele.siblingElements();
                                for (Element sibElemet : sibElemets) {
                                    newVersion = sibElemet.text();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

 if (onlineVersion != null && !onlineVersion.isEmpty()) {

                if (Float.valueOf(currentVersion) < Float.valueOf(onlineVersion)) {
                    //show anything
                   final String appPackageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName(); // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
                try {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                }
                }


            }
```

Comment: I have tried this every thing is working fine but in play store update button is showing on second time when we go from app to play store